# Can I pass the value from my iOS app to web page?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

In my app I'm using third party web survey tool. I load the survey into a UIWebView and the user has to fill this one out.

My question is, can I somehow pass some string parameters to that survey form to pre-fill some of the textfields?

Any kind of help is highly appreciated.

Comment: You can send parameters with the url by GET method : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1226363/send-parameters-to-a-local-file-in-a-uiwebview

Comment: You can execute javascript in your webview from your app.

Comment: can you please be more descriptive?

Comment: @DavidCheung did you notice that the question is from the app to the web? the post you're referring to is from web to app.

Comment: @EugeneGordin Please check out [WebViewJavascriptBridge](https://github.com/marcuswestin/WebViewJavascriptBridge) for sending messages between Obj-C and JavaScript in UIWebViews/WebViews.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You either could use UIWebView's [stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIWebView/stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:) to run your javascript which pre-fills the textfields.

or using the [WebViewJavascriptBridge](https://github.com/marcuswestin/WebViewJavascriptBridge).

Please check out this SO question:

[Communication between iOS's native app and webpage's javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8307620/communication-between-ioss-native-app-and-webpages-javascript)